# Difference between watts and watt-sec

Tags: watts, network, power-consumption

I want to know the difference between watt and watt-sec in the powe usage of the network devices. Is there any better approaches in considering the watts approach and watt-sec approach in the calculation of power consumption?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because google has many answers and the OP has shown zero signs of research.

Comment: Please google before posting https://www.google.com/search?q=difference+between+watt+and+watt+second&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Answer (score 1):

A watt-second is a joule and that is a measure of energy.

A watt is the unit of power.

Power consumption is measured in watts. Energy consumed is measured in joules or watt seconds (or kilo watt hours).

Energy is the mathematical integration of power.

Comment: I know the definitions that you told. But I am doing my research in the power consumption of the network devices.For that purpose I have to profile the power consumption.For that reason I asking which approach is better to profile the power usage of device?

Comment: As I said in my answer, power consumption is measured in watts therefore, the best approach (that you ask for) is to measure power. If you asked which profile is best for energy usage I would have said watt seconds or joules. In the absence of any other information these can be the only sensible answers.

Comment: Please can you tell me why watt-second approach is appropriate?

Comment: @Andyaka. An oversight?  Watt = available power. Consuming power (time) results in consuming energy.

Comment: @Decapod sorry but I don't understand the relevance for me. What oversight?

Comment: @Andyaka; Once you consume you introduce time. Power can not be consumed.

Comment: @Decapod I think we understand what 'power consumption' means, it's what the unwashed call 'the rate of energy consumption', and it needn't cause us to get to antsy. As long as power is measured in watts, and energy in joules, that will keep the dimensional books straight.

Answer (score 0):

If the power consumption of the device is constant, then power in watts is suitable.

If the power consumption varies, so has an idle level which rises when it's dealing with traffic, it may be easier to record and cost its power consumption in watt-s per day, or watt-hours per day, for specific traffic flows.

Note that watts times time per time comes back to watts again.

Comment: We are profiling the power consumption of the switch by generating udp traffic. I want to grab the energy values before generating the load on switch and after the completion of the job done on the switch. While grabing the power value there is sometimes a delay so we get the next power value in watt-sec. So,how can I remove the delayed power value in watt-sec approach

Comment: You **cannot** get a power value in watt-sec, that's like getting getting a speed in miles, watt-sec is an energy value, like miles is a distance. When you can talk consistently correctly and coherently about power and energy, then we can have a go at solving your problem.

Comment: Yeah I am grabing the energy value in watt-seconds for that particular traffic flow. But when the traffic has introduced on the system then I will grab energy value and after completion of the job I will grab energy value in Watt-sec.Here the problem is we have to consider before giving the job energy value and then we have to grab after the completion,then there may missing energy value which leads to not accurate energy consumption.